# HTML.Dropdownlist autocomplete

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Is there an html attribute that i can set so that my html.dropdownlist behaves like combobox, such that the user can type and have an autocomplete or suggest/suggest-append?
Id really love to not have to use telerik and rip up alot of my code.

Not sure if its relavent, but im using C#, asp.net mvc 2

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using javascript and possibly ajax on a regular textbox depending on what you want auto-completed.

Using JQuery it would be something like this:

```
$('#textboxID').bind('keydown', function(e)
{
     var data = $('#textboxID').Val;
     $.ajax({
          url: 'some/webservice', //If you're using MVC then your webservice url will be an action method url that returns the results you want.
          data: { userinput: data },
          type: "post",
          success: function (response)
          {
               //display context menu with suggestions from response
          }
      });
});
```

If you don't want an AJAX request sent for every keydown event then you could make the first keydown even start a js timer that checks every few seconds if the textbox value has changed, if so then make a new ajax call to update the suggestions drop down. Obviously, stop the interval timer onblur when the textbox loses focus.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the [jQuery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete).

Here's an example of code I wrote for a PHP project that uses a web service to retrieve the data to populate the list of items.  The plugin also has caching and options to delay calls as needed so you're not over consuming bandwidth.  As you can see, not a lot of code is required on your page once the library is referenced.

```
$('#title').autocomplete('ws/autocomplete.php',
{
  width: 400,
  selectFirst: false,
  matchContains: true,
  cacheLength: 1,
  extraParams: {t: "jobtitle"}
});
```

The only restriction is that your web service needs to return JSON data.